# Is it valid to return reference for artimetic operator overloading?

Tags: c++

As we know, we normally return a copy to a new class when overloading an arithmetic operator. As an example, `<<` operator is normally defined like this:

```
T1 operator<<(const T1& a, const T2& b) {
    // apply b
    return a;
}
```

But I wonder if it is generally valid to return a reference in this case or not. For example, is it possible that following code creates any invalid situation?

```
T1& operator<<(T1& a, const T2& b) {
    // apply b
    return a;
}
```

Why I need this? Let's assume I have a code like this:

```
class B {
public:
    B() {}
    ~B() { std::cout  << ss_.str() << "\n"; }

    template<typename T>
    B& operator<<(T val) {
        ss_ << val;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::stringstream ss_;
};

int main() {
    B{} << "str" << "abc" << 1;
    B{} << "str2" << "abc2" << 2;
}
```

In this code, constructor and destructor of type `T1` will be called only once which will be really suitable here. But if I return by value for the `<<` operator, constructor and destructor will be called for each temporary rvalues which is not great for my use case.

Is it possible that returning by reference create invalid code for overloading these operators?

Comment: Sure it's valid. Just don't return a reference to a temporary.

Comment: The question title is asking about arithmetic operators. Some arithmetic operators return a whole new object which is neither of the arguments and didn't already exist. For example `operator+` often can't return a reference while `operator+=` usually can.

Comment: It's valid to return whatever you like from an arithmetic operator.

Comment: It's fine to return a reference, but it is necessary to return a reference to an object that will exist when subsequently used.   Otherwise the behaviour is undefined when the returned reference is used.   An `operator+()` can return a reference, but - since it returns an object that is distinct from either of its operands - there is then the problem of ensuring the returned object exists for as long as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's not only valid, it's a common idiom when overloading `<<` for stream outputs. For example:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyData& data) {
  os << data.a << ',' << data.b << ',' << data.c;
  return os;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The rule about returning a reference is to never return a reference to a function local variable.  This also includes function parameters that are passed by value.

It gets a little trickier when dealing with reference parameters.

```
const T1& operator<<(const T1& a, const T2& b) {
    // apply b
    return a;
}
```

is problematic since `a` could be bound to a temporary.  That would mean that you are returning a reference to an object that is going to end at the end of the full expression the function call is in, which could cause trouble.

Using

```
T1 operator<<(T1& a, const T2& b) {
    // apply b
    return a;
}
```

You stop that from happening as now `a` can only bind to an lvalue so you don't have to worry about it living past the full expression the function is called in.